# Get only last child category link of products

Tags: terms

At the moment i have this code:

```
$collections = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

foreach( $collections as $collection ) {
    $link = get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/' . $collection->slug . '/';
    echo $link .'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
```

That outputs a product terms, taxanomies url of products. Problem is that code returns all of categories for one product like:

http://www.rebella.lv/aizsardzibu-no-saules-iedarbibas/  http://www.rebella.lv/dzilu-kondicionesanu/

I need only to show last child one category of products for example only one from list: product_cat.

Here is final working code:

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat', array('orderby' => 'term_id', 'order' => 'ASC') );
if ( !empty( $terms ) ) :
$project = array();
$project_url = array();
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $project[] = $term->name;
    $project_url[] = $term->slug;
}
echo '<category_full>' .$project[0] . ' &gt;&gt;'. $project[1]. ' &gt;&gt;'. $project[2]. '</category_full><category_link>' . get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/product-category/' . $project_url[0].'/'.$project_url[1].'/'.$project_url[2] . '/' . '</category_link>';
endif;
```

Comment: If you only need the last term you could use `array_pop()` - like so: `$term = array_pop($collections);` which will remove the last term from the `$collections` array and put it into `$term` as an object (if you're using `get_the_terms()` like above).

Comment: Add your solution as an actual answer please.

Comment: Not so much points to do that.

Comment: At worst, you only need to wait a few hours: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Foxsk8 the point is that your question doesn't haunt site as technically unanswered and other people benefit from you sharing your solution properly, thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Rarst, can you give rep points, i need to whait at the moment, becouse i am new one in wordpress stack? Then i put all code with code update for xml export of final project where this code is used. Tnx.